# how to drag only child elements inside nested ul tags using jquery ui draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

```
My list is something like this
<div id="jqxTree">
    <ul>
        <li>Parent1
            <ul>
                child1
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Parent2
            <ul>
                child2
            </ul>
            <ul>
                child2.1
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when i use jquery draggable its dragging entire list.How to i drag only child1,child2,child2.1 elements .To generalise i wanna drag only li elements inside ul which is inside li..

I tried using the below function but on mouseover the elements of li the elemnts get hidden

```
$('#jqxTree').delegate('li li', 'mouseover', function () {
    $(this).draggable({
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to jQuery API page:

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gzLFE/)

### jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jqxTree').on('mouseenter mouseover', 'li > ul', function () {
        $(this).draggable({
            revert: true,
            revertDuration: 0
        });

    });
});
```

In CSS, use `>` between parent and child elements.

Also you had `li li` instead of `li ul`.

Comment: hi actually this is working fine for static list but when i load list using ajax this is kind of behaving wierd.Whenever i click on parent the child elements dissapper and on dragging parent li all child elements are also getting dragged.I load data from ajax in form of tree using jqxtree jquery api and want this list to be draggable.Can u please suggest me if its dynamic should there be some other approach?